# Logon events detail in oracle

Tags: oracle, audit

I want to fetch the oracle user login detail for the month February. 
I tried the below query.

```
select distinct 
    os_username,username,userhost,terminal,timestamp,action_name,logoff_time 
from  dba_audit_session 
where timestamp between '01-FEB-2017' 
                    and '28-FEB-2017' 
order by timestamp;
```

but I need the IP address as well.
Can anyone help me! how to fetch the user IP address along each user session?

I am stuck here.

I have check `dba_audit_trail` table as well but didn't help.

I need the below columns:

```
username,os_user,logon_date,logoff_date,IPADDR, terminal, sessionid,hostname.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to AskTom, ["you can get the client ip address if you audit connect, it is in the comments column of the audit trail, you have to parse it out."](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:10583864460294). That's from 2003 but I think it is [still the case](https://www.dba-resources.com/oracle/finding-the-origin-of-failed-login-attempts/):

```
select comment$text from sys.aud$
```

or possibly:

```
select comment_text from dba_audit_trail;
```